# ndk-gdb with gradle flavor

Tags: android, gradle, ndk-gdb

In my android project I have a default flavor with a default package name for example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.my.default"
android:installLocation="auto">
```

And in my `build.gradle` I've added another flavor with a different package name:

```
productFlavors {
    another {
        applicationId 'com.my.another'  // This could override the package name defines in the `AndroidManifest.xml`
    }
}
```

After the APK has been installed into my device I want to attach the `ndk-gdb` and I get such issues:

1. If I install the `com.my.default` everything is fine.
2. If I install the `com.my.another`, the `ndk-gdb` fails because it was looking for the `com.my.default` which defines in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.
3. If I change the package name in the `AndroidManifest.xml` to `com.my.another` manually then `ndk-gdb` works.

And my question: Is there any way I could use `ndk-debug` to debug a flavor produced APK without altering the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android fixed this issue in the latest ndk-r10e https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56189